# Can't get the Captcha to appear

Tags: python, django, captcha, recaptcha

I have already installed django-recaptcha and included the captcha in installed apps. I am using the private key and public key from this page: https://github.com/praekelt/django-recaptcha.

I included the statement `captcha = ReCaptchaField()`. When I clicked the page, it appears like this:

> Captcha: Input error: k: Format of site key was invalid

Not sure where the error is. Need some guidance.

The html looks like this:

[image]

This is what i typed:

```
RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY = '98dfg6df7g56df6gdfgdfg65JHJH656565GFGFGs'
RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY = '76wtgdfsjhsydt7r5FFGFhgsdfytd656sad75fgh'
RECAPTCHA_USE_SSL = True
```

Comment: I don't see that error message in the source code of the github package. Where does the error exactly occur?

Comment: any ideas guys? still can't solve the problem....

Comment: I reached here with same problem , using my site specific public key, private  key solved my problem

https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#list

Answer (score 1):

According to the [following thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/recaptcha/QLVq9-llnbI), switching the private key and public key around fixes this error. That is, use

```
RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY = '98dfg6df7g56df6gdfgdfg65JHJH656565GFGFGs'
RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY = '76wtgdfsjhsydt7r5FFGFhgsdfytd656sad75fgh'
```

instead of the other way around as given in the [documentation](https://github.com/praekelt/django-recaptcha).

Comment: is yours the same way as the documentation?

Comment: What do you mean? Did I forget to switch them?

Comment: btw did u include the ssl stuff?

Comment: i am using models.Modelform instead of forms.Form. Might this be a reason for captcha not appearing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to register at [google to](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/whyrecaptcha) obtain you own api keys

Answer (score 0):

Enter your website URL without "http://". without "www" without "/" (at end of website name) . I mean simply add website name there for example , you can add "xyz.com". This will solve the problem.

https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin#whyrecaptcha